# Android TextView Linkify intercepts with parent View gestures

Tags: android, gesture, linkify

The problem is that if i Linkify the textView the underliyng ScrollView don't listen the sweep Gestures I've setted.Is there a way to have Linkify without messing with the underliyng view's gestures?
I tried to override ontouchEvent and return false to ACTION_MOVE but the scrollview's gesture needs the ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP event to function. Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`Linkify` applies to a movementMethod to the textView `LinkMovementMethod`. That movement method thought it implements a scrolling vertically method it overrides any other scrolling method the parent has. Although  `touchEvent` can be dispached to the parent, the specific parent `ScrollView` needed the whole sequence `ACTION_DOWN` , `ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP` to perform (sweep detection).

So the solution to my problem is after Linkify to remove the textView's scrolling method and handle the `LinkMovementMethod` link detection action in `onTouchEvent` of the textView.

```
@override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        TextView widget = (TextView) this;
        Object text = widget.getText();
        if (text instanceof Spanned) {
            Spannable buffer = (Spannable) text;

            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                x -= widget.getTotalPaddingLeft();
                y -= widget.getTotalPaddingTop();

                x += widget.getScrollX();
                y += widget.getScrollY();

                Layout layout = widget.getLayout();
                int line = layout.getLineForVertical(y);
                int off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x);

                ClickableSpan[] link = buffer.getSpans(off, off,
                        ClickableSpan.class);

                if (link.length != 0) {
                    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        link[0].onClick(widget);
                    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                         Selection.setSelection(buffer,
                                 buffer.getSpanStart(link[0]),
                                 buffer.getSpanEnd(link[0]));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
```

This way i have the Link_Click detection (performed only with the user touches the link and not the whole textview) and i don't have the whole LinkMovementMethod.

Comment: i'm glad it finally helped someone :D

Comment: Nice solution, clear and not hacky. I had to move `return true;` into the positive branch of internal if though to let the span be highlighted on steady touch.

Comment: The mentioned "remove the textView's scrolling method" is done via `textView.setMovementMethod(null);` and has to be called _after_ you've set the textView's text.

Answer (score 3):

@weakwire and @Ridicully answers are correct. I just created a small gist that you can re-use in your project.

This is the link: https://gist.github.com/amilcar-andrade/e4b76840da1dc92febfc

Comment: I have ported this class to Xamarin/C#: https://gist.github.com/pmachapman/a988348a93933ac359ebe0d6a5314467

Answer (score 0):

There is a small bad thing that
TextView::setText(...) method utilizing autoLink flag,

```
if (mAutoLinkMask != 0) {
        Spannable s2;

        if (type == BufferType.EDITABLE || text instanceof Spannable) {
            s2 = (Spannable) text;
        } else {
            s2 = mSpannableFactory.newSpannable(text);
        }

        if (Linkify.addLinks(s2, mAutoLinkMask)) {
            text = s2;
            type = (type == BufferType.EDITABLE) ? BufferType.EDITABLE : BufferType.SPANNABLE;

            /*
             * We must go ahead and set the text before changing the
             * movement method, because setMovementMethod() may call
             * setText() again to try to upgrade the buffer type.
             */
            mText = text;

            // Do not change the movement method for text that support text selection as it
            // would prevent an arbitrary cursor displacement.
            if (mLinksClickable && !textCanBeSelected()) {
                setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    }
```

So I spent a time to understand,
why i'm disabling links in **ListView** item,
but it obtains a link sometimes!

You need to set that flag in needed value
and then call a setText(...)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're saying here. Is this an answer to the question or are you trying to ask a new question?

Comment: It's mostly a note, cause I found this topic when search for "Linkify textview in ListView" problem