# How can I prevent swipe in TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a magazine type app which has TextViews on each of the pages, I need to be able to ignore the swipe gesture and pass it to the parent so that when the user drags sideways it moves to the next page instead of trying to scroll the TextView

Comment: TextView should not be scrollable, what is the parent of the textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you apply Linkify to the text or another `MovementMethod`? If so Linkify adds a new `MovementMethod` , `LinkMovementMethod` and consumes touch events.

Check [Android TextView Linkify intercepts with parent View gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236840/android-textview-linkify-intercepts-with-parent-view-gestures) so you have have link detection and touch events go to the parent

Use Linkify to style the text then override `onTouchEvent` of the `TextView` to handle only the links