# ListView onClick event doesn't fire with Linkified email address

Tags: android, listview, linkify

I have a straight forward ListView with a ListAdapter and custom onItemClick method for the list.
My ListView items are clickable to perform other functions. However, some of my ListView elements contain an email address that *should* be clickable too.

I found Linkify, and added it to the email address textview per the docs.

After doing so, the ListView item containing such a "clickable" textview is now no longer clickable to perform the other functions.

I have tried adding the OnItemClickListener after I create the entire view, to no avail :(

Any idea's on how to have my ListView items clickable eventhough they contain a Linkified textView?

---

My deepest appologies for not searching further before asking the question to begin with.
I have found the answer to my question, and posted it as an answer.

Comment: Please add some code so that we can get some idea about it.

Comment: Have you tried `android:descendantFocusability` in row layout?

Comment: @dziobas: I'm not sure where to put that. My code/layout is slightly more complex than the example I am showing you. The example code gives me the same problems though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Solution:**

After a lot of more searching (which I already did, but not far enough apparently), I finally found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236840/android-textview-linkify-intercepts-with-parent-view-gestures).

Example code:
My page (LinearLayout containing the listView) assigns a ListViewAdapter which creates the various ListView items, assigns itself as the OnClick listener and adds the ListView:

```
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
addView(list);
```

The ListViewAdapter creates each ListView item and assigns it's content, linkifying email addresses when needed:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
    textView.setText(<some email address>);
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
}
```

The solution is easy, using the code on the page I found. I created a LinkTextView class descending from TextView and added the method described on the page.
After the Linkify.addLinks call above I added the statement:

```
textView.setMovementMethod(null);
```

The ListView item and linkified text are now both clickable once again.

Again, my deepest appologies for not searching further before asking the question to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Just add android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to xml definition of list item.

Source: http://www.thekeyconsultant.com/2013/06/android-quick-tip-linkify-and-listviews.html?m=1