# ListView onItemLongClickListener does not prevent link taps

Tags: android, listview

**Environment:**
I have an Android `ListView` with rows that consist of TextViews containing some HTML with tappable links (`URLSpans`). On the ListView, I have set an `OnItemLongClickListener` to listen for long click events on individual rows.

**Goal:**
When I receive a long click event, I want to DISABLE taps on the links for the same touch event, but I'm not seeing how to do this. The long click fires correctly, but then as soon as I lift my finger, the link tap also fires.

**What I've Tried Already:**
I've tried returning true (and false) on the `onItemLongClick` method -- it doesn't seem to make a difference either way. I've tried to intercept the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` after a long click so that I can temporarily consume the link tap, but the `ACTION_UP` doesn't fire -- at least not on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more searching and found this answer to a similar question: [Android TextView Linkify intercepts with parent View gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236840/android-textview-linkify-intercepts-with-parent-view-gestures)

I used the concepts from this answer to solve my problem. I extended the `TextView` class and overrode `onTouchEvent` and look to see if I'm tapping on a link on touch down events. If I am, I save that link and "click" it programmatically on my `ListView.onItemClick` if I didn't encounter an `LongClick` first. Yuck.

If anybody else has a more elegant way to solve the problem, post it and I'll accept your answer if it works. If not, I'll accept my own answer in a few days.