# a textview in a listview' s row cannot click after setting descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"

Tags: android, android-listview, descendant

I write a customized item layout for a listview. The layout has many widgets and some will have its own clicklistener.

When I click the row, sometimes the listview' s onListItemClick work, but sometimes not.

After I spent some time searching, I find a way, setting **android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"** in the layout' s root. It works, but only one textview cannot work,(the clickable, fucusable attr have been tried). In the list' s adapter, I set the textview' s onClickListener, it works. But that' s not nature, does anyone know how to solve it?

btw, is there a way to distinguish diffderent widget' click? Now, no matter what I click(except that textview), the whole row' s background selector got changed.

many thanks!

// my list row layout root

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:padding="@dimen/medium"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

// the awful textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault"
        android:layout_below="@id/nick"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nick"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

---

update

the textview uses Linkify to provide some links functionalities.

Comment: set the property focusable and focusableOnTouch mode property and clickable porperty to false in the textview xml

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille I set them all false, but when I click the textview, the list' s ``onListItemClick`` is still not called.

Comment: set the linear layout to non-clickable also, and set them in the code also, that is, in the getView method set the properties to false via code also

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille sorry for my inexperince. I didn' t mention **The textview use Linkify to provide some links**. I searched the web just now and commentted the Linkify code, it works... However, the links must be kept. any ideas?

Comment: if you really need the links then in that case, the onClick is the way to go for the links , where by when the link is clicked on, open the url in the webview. (do this in the getView method)

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille Thanks, I find a sulution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236840/android-textview-linkify-intercepts-with-parent-view-gestures/7327332#7327332) . plus, is there a way to distinguish diffderent widget' click? Now, no matter what I click(except that textview), the whole row' s background selector got changed.

Comment: Yes possible, just the way you have written the rows selector, when you click the textview you can have its own selector too and place it in the textColor of the textview. like android:textColor="@drawable/demo_selector"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spenting some time trying, I solved both.

1. the first. if your customized listview' s layout has a textview which has been set  `autolink` or `Linkify` in the code, the click event in the textview won' t affect the list' s row. You have to **extends** your own `TextView` and **override** `onTouchEvent` method. please see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236840/android-textview-linkify-intercepts-with-parent-view-gestures/7327332#7327332)
2. the second. just set in the customized listview' s root node: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`, and then, in your widget which will have its own `onClickListener`, set `android:clickable="true"`, it works for me.

hope it useful for those you encounter the same:-)