# Onclick not able to detect in listrow in android

Tags: android

**What is happening**::

- I am not able to detect on click for my listrow for a listview
- I am gussing it has to do with focusability because if i use a
  different xml for row i am able to detect onclick
- So how can i detect onclick for my adapter row as mentioned below

---

**My Xml**::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/listview_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:shrinkColumns="0"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBufRestName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="Restaurant Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBufDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:src="@drawable/distance_flag" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBufDistance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="1600"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBufDistanceUnit"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:text="km"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBufType"
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Buffet Type"
                android:textColor="#636262"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/restRatingBar"
                android:layout_width="61dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/star_5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBufTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="12:00 Am to 12:00 Pm"
                android:textColor="#636262"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.82"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtOnlinePrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Txt" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnOnlinePrice"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_online_selector"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="   Buy Now"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2.07"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtReservePrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Txt" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnReservePrice"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_reserve_selector"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
                    android:text="Reserve"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgBufLogo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtBufOffId"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRating"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you are not able to detect onClik on any view or onItemClick on listview ?

Comment: @Manmohan .... I resolved using android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" for root view

Comment: good to know that , i also found something abt ur problem as i removed ur TableLayout and added focusable false on focusable view and now i am able to click on list.

Comment: @Manmohan ..... Thanks for sharing .... Post that as a solution ...ill accept it as the answer

Comment: ok i'll add that sol as answer but due to removing tablelayout its row is not looking as u want but working fine as soln.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can made all focusable view false and then applying onItemClick or any other , u can work with listview easily.

you can see related project sample with given xml. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6C9Pqrvc_CWWXBvQ3ZtTEhzYTA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it, just like below

```
ListView lvNews = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvNews);
lvNews.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            // your code

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it using

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

[This link helped me in achieving my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21909839/1083093)